# Running podman on RH 8.8 continues to give "no read access to runc binary" error

Tags: redhat, podman

On a stig'd Redhat 8.8 machine I cannot get podman to run hello world or build a simple app and continue to get a no read access error

Running commmand

root>podman run hello

Produces

root>*Error: OCI runtime error: runc: you have no read access to runc binary file
runc*

fapolicy: turned off

selinux: in permissive mode

and

*-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 10253456 Feb  3  2023 /usr/bin/runc*

Any ideas or debug tips?